# How to make rake task dependent on file and another task

Tags: ruby, rake

I have two rake tasks that need to be dependent on a file, as well as another rake task.  Here is what I've tried:

```
task :dependencies do
  # Install some pacman packages if necessary
end

# the :build task should be dependent on output.pdf and the dependencies task
task :build => [:dependencies, 'output.pdf']

# the file task should also be dependent on dependencies (in case it's run directly)
file 'output.pdf' => [:dependencies, 'output.md'] do
```

How can I tell a file task to depend on another rake task *as well as* its input file?  Also, how can I tell a regular task to be dependent on a file task and a regular task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've got works for me.  I can't diagnose further without output.

Rakefile:

```
task :dependencies do
  puts "installing dependencies"
end

task build: ['dependencies', 'output.pdf']

file 'output.pdf' => ['dependencies', 'output.md'] do
  File.write 'output.pdf', ''
end
```

Running build:

```
$ ls
Rakefile    output.md
$ rake -t build
** Invoke build (first_time)
** Invoke dependencies (first_time)
** Execute dependencies
installing dependencies
** Invoke output.pdf (first_time)
** Invoke dependencies 
** Invoke output.md (first_time, not_needed)
** Execute output.pdf
** Execute build
$ ls
Rakefile    output.md   output.pdf
```

Running output.pdf:

```
$ rm output.pdf
$ rake -t output.pdf
** Invoke output.pdf (first_time)
** Invoke dependencies (first_time)
** Execute dependencies
installing dependencies
** Invoke output.md (first_time, not_needed)
** Execute output.pdf
$ ls
Rakefile    output.md   output.pdf
```

PS: Rake doesn't care about symbols vs strings in task or dependency names.

Comment: Interesting - if symbol vs. strings doesn't matter in dependencies, how does rake figure out if the dependency is a task or a file?